# energy of electrons outside an atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons

The higher the quantum number(energy levels)m the higher the energy. 
What does the energy refers to? Kinetic energy, potential energy, or the total mechanic energy?

Answer (score 2):

The energy is the energy required to remove the electron from the atom to an infinite distance, or alternatively it's the energy released when you bring an electron from an infinite distance into the orbital.

We generally define the potential energy at infinity to be zero. This is a convention because potential energy has a global gauge symmetry and we could choose any value we want for the energy at infinity. However zero is an obvious and convenient choice.

So, for example, we say the energy of the $1s$ orbital in hydrogen is -13.6eV and by this we mean it takes 13.6eV of energy to completely remove the electron i.e. ionise the atom. More generally the energy of the $n$th orbital is:

$$ E_n = - \frac{m e^4}{2\hbar^2n^2} $$

This energy is the sum of the kinetic and potential energy of the electron. The potential and kinetic energies are:

$$ V_n = - \frac{me^4}{\hbar^2 n^2} $$

$$ T_n = \frac{me^4}{2 \hbar^2 n^2} $$

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to show that $E_n = T_n + V_n$.

If you're interested, the figures above are an example of the [virial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem), which phrased very approximately says that for a bound object $2T = -V$. A quick glance at the equations above should convince you this is the case for the hydrogen atom.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you think of an electron of an atom, not outside an atom because this is usually referred as a "*free electron*".
This can be important for the "*free electron gas*" or the "*free electrons*" in solid, but that is not what you want here i think.

When speaking about the quantum numbers of an atom, the so called *principal quantum number*  "n" referers to the orbital of the atom which the electron occupies. Higher "n" means the electron will most of the time be further away from the nucleus and in this way its energy is higher.

The energy is potential energy as this is what you consider when you speak about quantum numbers.

Comment: This is incorrect. The principal quantum number $n$ is one the labels used for stationary states of the hydrogen-like atom. These states are eigenstates of the Hamiltonian which is the *total* energy of the system: potential plus kinetic.

Comment: @dgh is correct. If one considers the Bohr atom as a good approximation to the quantum solution the velocity of the electron in the energy level would correspond to the expectation value of the velocity for the orbital around the hydrogen atom. On the other hand, at this quantum mechanical level it has little meaning it is better to talk just of energy level.